# How to convert hex string starting with 0 to bytes with certain lenght in python

Tags: python, parsing

I want to convert:

```
'01' -> \x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'0001' -> \x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I tried something like this:

```
int(data,16).to_bytes(16, byteorder='little')
```

but this is not working when string starting with '00'. Is there some other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) and [`bytes.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.ljust):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('01').ljust(16, b'\0')
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> bytes.fromhex('0001').ljust(16, b'\0')
b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```